# Firebase/Firestore: save or update in real time when user change values

Tags: performance, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm developing a mobile application written using React-native and firebase. I'd like to store in realtime user's values without the user trigger.

My concern is about performance and best practice: is ok to update a document when the user change, for example, a textfield? In other word, is of make something like:

```
onDataChange = (obj) => {
   firebase.firestore().collection("collection").doc(obj.id).update(cvObj).then(() => {
// ok
        }).catch(e => {
// notify the user about the error
        })
    }
```

What about offline persistence?
Many thanks

Comment: Yes, it's OK if it meets the needs of your application and your budget.

Comment: thanks for your feedback!
My concern is about performance.. this operation should be done each time the user change a text field... i don't know if is a good implementation..

Comment: The question is unclear but it appears you are asking about writing out a few bytes of data from a textField? Firebase is incredibly fast so that update to the database would probably take .023 seconds with a good internet connection.